# Compare data frame with vector and create new variable for matched value

Tags: r, compare, dplyr

I have a data frame with 600 rows which has a character variable (ids) that contains numbers separated by comma.

```
name    ids
x     8,5,23,56,78,44,54
y      5,7,23,44
z      8,44,2
```

I wanted to compare the above values with three different vectors which contains numeric values.

```
a=c(5,7,9,3)
b=c(8,23,78,66,4)
c=c(44,54,2,90)
```

I need to create three new columns for the vectors in the data frame which contain the values from ids that matches more than once in the each vector

```
name    ids                a          b           c
x    8,5,23,56,78,44,54    NA      8,23,78       44,54
y    5,7,23,44             5,7       NA           NA
z    8,44,2                NA        NA           44,2
```

I really do not have any idea how to compare this since both are different types and once I compare and how to get the seperate the values like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can place the vectors in a `list`, loop through them, `split` the 'ids' column in the 'data.frame' by ',' into a `list`, subset the vectors based on the elements found `%in%` the split `list`, create an exception to return NA when the `length` of the subset is 1 or `else` we `paste` (i.e. `toString`) it together and assign the output back to new columns in 'df1'.

```
df1[letters[1:3]] <- lapply(list(a, b, c), function(x) 
     sapply(strsplit(df1$ids, ","), function(y) {
       x1 <- x[x %in% as.numeric(y) ]
     if(length(x1)>1) toString(x1) else NA 
}))
```

Comment: That works flawlessly akrun. One more thing, instead of letters, say if I want to name the column as name of the vectors what should be done. If each vector is named as commercial, regular, urgent instead of a,b,c respectively. Thank you so much.

Comment: @ssan You can use `df1[c("a", "b", "c")] <- `  .  It is easy to do this manually if there are only a couple of columns.